# How to get today record with unix time in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have stored `php time()` in to database table with field created. That time stored in my database successfully.

Now I am willing to write a query which gets only today record from that table.

I have done something like this but not workin `strtotime("2012-12-12");`

For eg: I have stored this time in table `1355209509`. So I want to retrieve all records of this date from mysql.

Comment: What is the datatype you have defined for your column ?

Comment: use other datatypes e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this query -

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(<unix_time_column>)) = CURDATE()
```